# Windows 10 VPN Name Server with slash

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn

Windows 10 doesn't allow me to create a VPN connection to a server with slash "/" in the nameserver.

Server: foo1.foo2.com/foo3

Without the /foo3 the user can't connect in the VPN server.

Any advice ? Or if Windows 10 denied it, some program to manage the VPN connections

Thanks.

Comment: As the slash is not part of the server name it's understandable it wouldn't allow you to if it's a field for the server name. It depends on what kind of VPN Service you're using you should look into the documentation of it. An alternative client could be OpenVPN for example but you'd have to craft the configuration file accordingly. How did you verify that it works with `/foo3`?

Comment: I use Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client, but not is very good for managing.